# PRを残したままリモートブランチ名を変更したい

Tags: git, github

github でプルリクを出して、レビューをもらったりした後に、ブランチ名を修正したいことが稀によくあります。プルリクを消さないまま、ブランチ名を変更するにはどうすればよいのでしょうか？

```
直接リモートブランチの名前を変更するコマンドは無いようなので、別リモートブランチ(remote_new)にコピーしてremote_oldを削除する方法をとった。

git checkout -b ローカルブランチ名 origin/remote_old
git push origin ローカルブランチ名:remote_new
git push origin :remote_old
```

こういうやり方だと、プルリクが消えてしまいます。

Comment: [本家](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007578/renaming-a-branch-while-on-pull-request)に同じようなQAがありました。期待されている操作はできなそうです。名前を変更したブランチで新しいPRを作るしかないようです。

Answer (score 3):

@ksaito さんも仰っているように、 https://stackoverflow.com/q/20007578/3090068 にて、同じ内容の質問がなされています。 git 上のリモートへのプッシュ操作として、ブランチのリネームが存在していない以上、必然的に削除・新規作成を行うしかなく、それうけて github 的には PR をクローズするしかない様子です。

現実的な解としては、新しい PR を作成、古い PR をクローズ、新しい方ないし古い方から、移行先・元を refer する、ではないでしょうか。